# In Excel 2013 how can you make every distinct number value have a matching distinct colour?

Tags: worksheet-function, colors, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table of computed numbers in excel (different every time it is computed), for example:

```
   A B C D E
1. 9 8 9 9 1
2. 7 1 1 1 9
3. 1 6 5 2 9
4. 6 6 3 2 2
5. 3 3 2 3 7
```

In the example I have used a small collection of low value numbers but in reality it could be a very large collection or very low value or high value numbers (like -52353223 or +496058).

I wish to highlight (cell background colour preferably) all distinct values with a matching distinct colour.  For example, all 9's would be red, all 8's would be blue, and all 7's would be green, and so on and so forth.

I've tried conditional formatting, but this isn't useful because it doesn't make a big enough difference between the colours for similar values.  It also isn't an option to manually find/replace numbers with formatting either - it has to be done automatically.

Does Excel have a way to do this built in, or will it requite a VBA script or some other method?

Thank you!

Comment: Conditional Formatting > Color Scales are a good place to start

Comment: [relevant](http://superuser.com/questions/656864/excel-dual-graded-color-scales)

Comment: @CallumDS33 The problem with the colour scales is that, if you have some low value numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 with some high value numbers like 10000, 20000, 30000, the lower value number's colour gradient will have such an insignificant difference that it will look exactly the same

Comment: @Raystafarian thanks for that link, the code could probably be modified to do what I want, which I might have to do if there is no other solution