# Excel conditional formatting gradient text color

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, gradient

I am familiar with the conditional formatting in excel where you can fill the background of a range of cells with gradient colors according to their value. You can either choose a 2-color scale or a 3-color scale. However, this only seems possible for background colors of the cells but not the text/foreground color. Is this something I can do at all in excel?

Comment: I might try to start http://superuser.com/questions/656864/excel-dual-graded-color-scales/692584#692584 - you're going to have to write it

Comment: gradient formatting of the fore color is part of microsoft word.  For the most part, not viable in excel as something that can be programmed. Exceptions is vba, or paste a html or word object that will have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually format individual letters in cells, however there is no automatic (macro, conditional formatting...) way in Excel for managing parts of the same cell differently.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a constant number of entries, you could use top 10, 5 , 1 function  and define font colours by category